# How to display elements inside an arrayList with two CSS style?

Tags: css, angular, arraylist

I'm writing a code where there's an arrayList having two names in it i.e.Bob & Steve and i want to display them such that if Bob is displayed it should be green in color and if Steve is displayed it should be REd in color.

Component.CSS

```
.Bob{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:green;
}
.Steve{
color:red;
}
```

Component.HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" *ngFor="let st of Names;"> 
  <div class="col-2">
    <p class="Bob">{{st}}</p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-2">
    <p class="Steve">{{st}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

in Component.Ts

```
Names:string[]=['Bob','Bob','Steve','Bob','Steve']; in Component.Ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide class based on condition .

Modify your code like below :

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row" *ngFor="let st of Names;"> 
  <div class="col-2">
    <p  [ngClass]="(st=='Bob')?'Bob':'Steve'">{{st}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the working example  :

[Working Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrphfc)

Comment: this worked i want to do it in the simplest way..is there any simplest way..?? because ngClass haven't been taught to me neither the use of "?"..SO if there is any simplest way please do help me with that.

Comment: @amansolanki  these are  the  fundamental concepts of Angular. Easiest , concise and understandable . Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: @programoholic, in this particular case, you can use simple [ngClass]="st"

Comment: @programoholic  ok this is a bit easy for two elements..what if i have more than 10 elements in the array??

Comment: @Eliseo can you help me with the same doubt

Comment: @AmanSolanki you mean to say you have 10 elements in array and you need to display different colors for all ?

Comment: ` <p  [ngClass]="st">{{st}}</p>`  will help . Note that you need to add class in css file . I have updated the stackBlitz as well.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw1f8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  i have submitted the stckbliz it will help you more to understand my problem..as by pressing each button it should add in the array well as with the provided CSS styling

Comment: @AmanSolanki create different question its not in sync with current question asked

Comment: its simple like its an score of a match by pressing the above digits you indicate the run scored on that ball and different runs had different property to display.

Comment: @AmanSolanki, I'm not sure what do you want to obtain, I try to answer, see bellow

Answer (score 0):

When we have a large number of elements and we can showed it with different background we can adopt several approaches.

1. Has an array of styles/background and use the index

   ```
    colors=['red','yellow','green'...]
    <div *ngFor="let item of items;let index=i>
        <div [style.background-color]="colors[i]">item.data</div>
    </div>
   ```
2. The background was a "property" of "items"

   ```
    items=[{data:...,color:'Red'},{data:...,color:'yellow'},...]
    <div *ngFor="let item of items;let index=i>
        <div [style.background-color]="item.background">item.data</div>
    </div>
   ```

We can use

```
[style.css_property]="value"
//or 
[className]="class"
//or 
[ngClass]="{'class':condition}"
```

In your case, Aman, I think that it's better that your "items" has a property "class" that was, e.g.

```
{data:...,class:'bold-true green-true'}
```

So, when you want add a item, you can make a function

```
getClass()
{
   let class="";
   if (this isBold)
      class="isBlod-true";
   if (this.isCut)
      class=class+" isCut-true";
   if (this.isGreen)
      class=class+" isGreen-true";
   ...
 return class
}
```

And when you add an item, you can do

```
items.push({data:...,class:this.getClass()})
```

Then the code

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;let index=i>
 <div [className]="item.class">item.data</div>
</div>
```

make the trick